# MySQL Query works on Server but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Problem solved!

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

The following mysql query works fine if i run that directly on the server. If i try to run this via php i got no error nor a result... any suggestions?

*Query*

```
Select Distinct 
    users.last_name, 
    accounts.name, 
    Max(Distinct tasks.date_entered) as credate, 
    accounts_cstm.kategorie_c, 
    accounts_cstm.geschaeftsfeld_c as Geschäftsfeld, 
    Count(tasks_cstm.betreff_c),
    tasks_cstm.nz_c,
    tasks_cstm.betreff_c 
From 
    tasks Left Join users On tasks.created_by = users.id 
    Inner Join accounts On tasks.parent_id = accounts.id 
    Left Join tasks_cstm On tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c 
    Inner Join accounts_cstm On accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c 
Where tasks_cstm.betreff_c In ('Call', 'Angebot', 'Mail') 
    And tasks.deleted = 0 
Group By 
    accounts.name, tasks_cstm.betreff_c 
Having 
    (tasks_cstm.betreff_c = 'Call') Or 
    (tasks_cstm.betreff_c = 'Angebot') Or 
    (tasks_cstm.betreff_c = 'Mail') 
Order By 
    credate Desc;
```

*PHP Code*

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpw);
if (!$conn || !mysql_select_db('sugar', $conn)) {
    echo "con error"; }
else {
    $query = "[query from above]";
$push = mysql_query($query);
if (!$push) {
        echo "query error"; }
    else {
        echo "query ok";
        mysql_free_result($push); }
mysql_close($conn); }
```

Any simple query works fine...

Thanks

Comment: use mysql_error() to see whats going on !!

Comment: Can you show how you included that query in your code? My guess is you made a mistake there. Like missing white space when concatening strings.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` function to write new code. They are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects instead.

Comment: oh thanks, missed that... problem is gone... UTF8 ftw...

Comment: In php code, you supplied, there is no code to fetch the results after you've queried it, have you used mysql_fetch_assoc or similar fetch functions?

Comment: @user3511168, create an answer and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Missed an "As Geschäftsfeld"...

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
print_r($row);
```